# Magento: can't capture dispatched event

Tags: php, events, magento, observers

In order to develop an automated order status changer based on payment method and event type, I created the following module:

/GT/OrderFlo/etc/config.xml

```
    <!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <gt_orderflow>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </gt_orderflow>
    </modules>

    <global>

        <models>            
            <orderflow>
                <class>GT_OrderFlow_Model</class>
            </orderhook>
        </models>

        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <order_payment_pending_autostatus>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>orderflow/observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </order_payment_pending_autostatus>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
            <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <order_invoice_pending_autostatus>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>orderflow/observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </order_invoice_pending_autostatus>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
            <sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <order_complete_autostatus>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>orderflow/observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </order_complete_autostatus>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after>                        
        </events>

    </global>
</config>
```

/GT/OrderFlow/Model/Observer.php

```
class GT_OrderFlow_Model_Observer
{
public function implementOrderStatus($event)
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $payment_method = $this->_getPaymentMethod($order);
    $this->_log('In implementOrderStatus with payment method: '.$payment_method);
    Mage::log('In implementOrderStatus with payment method: '.$payment_method);
    $next_status = "";
    return $this;
}

private function _getPaymentMethod($order)
{
    return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
}

private function _log($message)
{
    return Mage::log($message, null, 'gt_orderflow.log');
}
}
```

The code was replicated from http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/.

But how can I get it to fire the observer after `sales_order_place_after` event?

Comment: try making an order that would be shipped to multiple addresses.

Comment: everything seems to be fine. Forgive me the trivial question - did you flush the config cache?

Comment: yes I flushed everything and made like 20 orders :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your module loaded at all? You will need a file in `/app/etc/modules`. On a related note, I see that you refer to your module as `<gt_orderflow>` but the class prefix is `GT_OrderFlow`. On a case sensitive filesystem, this is important and will not work this way. The nodes under `config/modules` are mapped to the module path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I have MagnetoDebugToolbar and I can see my GT_OrderFlow loaded. I have a file on /app/etc/modules with the following code:
`<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <GT_OrderFlow>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>community</codepool>
        </GT_OrderFlow>
   </modules>
</config>`

Comment: So, the module configuration is loaded, great (although it should be `codePool`). Now what exactly is the problem? Did you really make sure that your observer method did *not* get called? I.e. with a debugger or `Mage::log` in the *first line* of the method?

Comment: I copied the codepool from a core config module, so I was hoping it was ok. As for the observer method, if you can see the code on my initial question, the mage log is made on the fourth line but I can easily pass it to the first line and test it out...

Comment: You're right. It's codePool and not codepool. Nonetheless it doesn't work :/

Comment: fab, your tips payed off. After changed to codePool, I noted something different. Turned all warnings and notices and he noticed the typo on orderhook in config.xml. Now I changed all case sensitive references and corrected the typo. Trying it out again...

Comment: Well, it kinda worked. I got an email saying the payment transaction failed.
Payment transaction failed. Reason Method "implementOrderStatus" is not defined in "". I even changed `<class>orderflow/observer</class>` to `<class>GT_OverFlow_Model_Observer</class>` and got no better.

Comment: Found the problem. Stupid and silly me, when I copied the code from atwix, the clipboard had <!--?php on top instead of just <?php. The system didn't recognized it to be a php file of course...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo

```
<models>             
    <orderflow>  
    -----^
        <class>GT_OrderFlow_Model</class>
    </orderhook>
    -----^
</models>
```

Comment: Yes R.S. Thank you for your notice. I detected it after I got changed codepool to codePool.